# flutter redux StoreConnector vs StoreBuilder

Tags: android, redux, dart, flutter

I am using [Flutter redux](https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_redux) for state management and what I don't understand is why do we have both `StoreConnector`and `StoreBuilder`? 
What is the difference between the two, other than the parameters they except?
 Is there a specific reason as to when should we use any one of them?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The difference is basically on the scope of changes.

I'd recommend for the `StoreConnector` pretty much every time, except for very simple cases.

`StoreBuilder` always listens on the entire store. `StoreConnector` converts the store to a widget-specific viewmodel; this is what lets redux be smart about what parts of the tree need be updated when the store changes.

If you have `StoreBuilders` everywhere, all of them will be updated every time there is a change in the store.

Comment: From what I found, the `builder` method of both `StoreConnector` and `StoreBuilder` are called, even if that part of the store is not updated.

Comment: You need to override the equal and hashcode methods in your viewmodel classes.

Comment: and do not forget to set `distinct` to `true` while constructing `StoreConnector`.